# One form across two pages django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to create a form that does the following: the user specifies the number of questions that they want to ask and then on the next page, the user is able to fill out the relevant details pertaining to the number of questions that they to ask. I was wondering if there is a simple way to do this using django forms?

My approach is as follows: 
I use one form to record the number of questions that the user wants to ask with a general description, then when the user clicks submit/next, the next view would create a form with those number of questions; however, I'm running into a complication when trying to use this method. I want to link the first form to the second form, but not sure how to because I can't preserve any information in the view from each call.

Is there a better way of going about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django 1.8, the [`django.contrib.formtools` module was moved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/formtools/#django-contrib-formtools) into a separate package, [django-formtools](http://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). It includes the [FormWizard](http://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#module-formtools.wizard.views), which is the standard tool you'd use to create a form that spans multiple pages and/or steps.

Answer (score 4):

You certainly can preserve information between views. Perhaps the easiest way to do this is in URL parameters; your first view can redirect to "/second_view/?number_of_questions=5" and the second view can access `request.GET['number_of_questions']`.

An alternative, which is particularly useful if you have a lot of data, would be to use the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/); add the data to the session on submit in the first view, and pop it out in the second.